# React does not call function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, this

```
  teste(){
   console.log('a');
  }

 componentDidMount() {
   // firebase things?
   firebase.database().ref('Matheus').on('value', function(snapshot){
     itens = snapshot.val();
     itens.forEach((data) => {
     firebase.storage().ref(data).getDownloadURL().then(this.teste);
   });
 });
```

Code works. It is only impossible to call the function **this.teste**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [context of `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) has changed when running inside the inner function.
Either store `this` in a temp variable to use it inside the function:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    const that = this; // holding the context for this
   // firebase things?
   firebase.database().ref('Matheus').on('value', function(snapshot){
     itens = snapshot.val();
     itens.forEach((data) => {
     firebase.storage().ref(data).getDownloadURL().then(that.teste); // using that instead of this
   });
 });
```

Or use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which will use a lexical context for `this`:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    const that = this; // holding the context for this
   // firebase things?
   firebase.database().ref('Matheus').on('value', (snapshot) => { // arrow function instead
     itens = snapshot.val();
     itens.forEach((data) => {
     firebase.storage().ref(data).getDownloadURL().then(that.teste);
   });
 });
```